# Guess random number, stops when random and guess are same

Tags: java, random, numbers

```
import java.util.*;
/*
10,100,1000  intervals of 10
App generates a number:unkown
person enters a number


Miguel Castaneda
*/

class GenerateNumber{

public static void main(String args[])
throws java.io.IOException {

int num;

/*
loopTimes =  System.in.read(); //casted
System.out.println("Loop Times is: " +loopTimes)
*/ //one byte at a time gets read


System.out.println("How many times do you want to loop?");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int loopTimes = sc.nextInt();       //new scanner

System.out.println("Loop Times is: " +loopTimes);


System.out.println("What would be the max number to guess?");
//genearte random number named :randomNumber

int maxNumber = sc.nextInt();       
Random generator = new Random();
int i = generator.nextInt(maxNumber);


int guess = generator.nextInt(maxNumber);
System.out.println("Random number is: " + i); 
System.out.println("Guess number is: " + guess); 

   while(i!=guess){
if(guess==i)
System.out.println("Guess and Random are same"); 

guess = generator.nextInt(maxNumber);//guess until random and guess are same
System.out.println("Guess number is: " + guess); //print out everytime guess and random arent the same
counter++;
}



//loopTimes =  System.in.read(); //casted

//if(num==rand)System.out.println("Right");
//else System.out.println("Wrong");

}}
```

How many times do you want to loop?
10
Loop Times is: 10
What would be the max number to guess?
10
Random number is: 0
Guess number is: 2
Guess number is: 4
Guess number is: 5
Guess number is: 6
Guess number is: 0

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 0.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
I want the computer to keep randomizing the number until random and guess are same I don't want to keep entering numbers.
The code never shows that "Guess and random are same" line instead it just keeps randomizing the guess and leaves random same. How do I change this?

Comment: there is no loop

Comment: Look up the keyword `while` (or `for` and `break`)

Comment: loopTimes varible is nowhere used

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want it to I think:

```
import java.util.*;
/*
10,100,1000  intervals of 10
App generates a number:unkown
person enters a number
*/

class GenerateNumber {

    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

    int randomNumber;
    int loopTimes;

    /*
    loopTimes =  System.in.read(); //casted
    System.out.println("Loop Times is: " +loopTimes)
    */ //one byte at a time gets read


    System.out.println("How many times do you want to loop?");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    loopTimes = sc.nextInt();       //new scanner

    System.out.println("Loop Times is: " +loopTimes);


    System.out.println("What would be the max number to guess?");

    int maxNumber = sc.nextInt();       
    Random generator = new Random();
    randomNumber = generator.nextInt(maxNumber);

    for (int i=1;i<=loopTimes;i++) {
        System.out.println("Guess number " + i + ":");
        int guess = sc.nextInt();
        if (randomNumber == guess) {
            System.out.print("YOU WIN! Random number was " + randomNumber);
            sc.close();
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Keep Guessing!");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("SORRY! YOU LOSE!  The number was " + randomNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ShakeebAyaz , it was kind of fun to write

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
while(i< loopCount) {
i++;
 System.out.println("Guess number " + i + ":");
    int userGuess = sc.nextInt();
    if (randomNumber == userGuess) {
        System.out.print("Success Random number was " + randomNumber);
        sc.close();
       break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Keep Guessing!");
    }

}
sc.close();
if(i==loopTimes)
System.out.println("Failed  The number was " + randomNumber);
```